# Smplayer problem on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, video, mplayer, smplayer

Ever since I upgraded to 14.04 I've had problems with my smplayer playback. I thought it might be an upgrade issue and so I fresh-installed the OS and installed smplayer first thing, still the same issue. Below is what the playback looks like, the colors are displaced. Many videos also run far faster than usual. How do I solve this issue? Smplayer was installed using the following commands:

`sudo add-apt-repository ppa:rvm/smplayer
 sudo apt-get update
 sudo apt-get install smplayer smtube smplayer-themes smplayer-skins`

Edit1: More information:

The graphic card is

`01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Pitcairn PRO [Radeon HD 7850] (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: XFX Pine Group Inc. Device 3264`

No changes have been made to smplayer, in-fact no commands are run at all other than installing Ubuntu with updates and running the above mentioned commands to install smplayer.

Edit2: Update

I removed and purged smplayer and then installed smplayer2 and the problem persists in smplayer2. I should mention that the problem does not occur in all files, only some. Moreover removing smplayer2 and going back to smplayer causes the problem to be solved for these files, but appear for some other files that rendered properly earlier (displaced colors, same problem), which is very odd.

Thanks.

[image]

Comment: What is you SMPlayer configuration? All default or do you use some special video backend? Have you tried other backends? If you use hardware acceleration, what graphics chip do you use? I'm using SMPlayer2 (which is a bit different) and Intel HD Graphics. I had no issues so far.

Comment: Updated to add more information to answer your question.

Comment: Had some problem, kind of solved it by changing the video-output in mplayer config from `vo=xv`to `vo=gl`